# How do I translate a UV set of faces keeping the vertical or horizontal axis fixed?

Tags: uv

How do I translate a UV set of faces keeping the vertical or horizontal axis fixed?

Tried with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>, <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>, no way: <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> is for sharp movement, <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> is for snap, both of them are not sharp enough, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> does nothing.

Comment: The keyboard-shortcut 'grammar'  is pretty consistent across the application, 3D View, UV editor, Node editor, etc. etc, It's worth getting at least the basic transform shortcuts : G Move, R Rotate, S Scale, and their constraints, under your belt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>G</kbd> for the grab command and you can constrain movement by pressing either <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> afterward.

Comment: Note that G+Axis works across all ofther editors in blender as well (like the graph editor, movie clip editor, etc)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't imagine that ```G``` was working also in the UV editor, as you can already manipulate with the bounding box!